# How do I create multiple model instances with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to save and update multiple  instances using the Django Rest Framework with one API call. For example, let's say I have a "Classroom" model that can have multiple "Teachers". If I wanted to create multiple teachers and later update all of their classroom numbers how would I do that? Do I have to make an API call for each teacher?

I know currently we can't save nested models, but I would like to know if we can save it at the teacher level.
Thanks!

Comment: Here is similar question with solution that worked for me:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439672/django-rest-framework-batch-create/31415417#31415417

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I know this was asked a while ago now but I found it whilst trying to figure this out myself.

It turns out if you pass `many=True` when instantiating the serializer class for a model, it can then accept multiple objects.

This is mentioned [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects) in the django rest framework docs

For my case, my view looked like this:

```
class ThingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """This view provides list, detail, create, retrieve, update
    and destroy actions for Things."""
    model = Thing
    serializer_class = ThingSerializer
```

I didn't really want to go writing a load of boilerplate just to have direct control over the instantiation of the serializer and pass `many=True`, so in my serializer class I override the `__init__` instead:

```
class ThingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        many = kwargs.pop('many', True)
        super(ThingSerializer, self).__init__(many=many, *args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Thing
        fields = ('loads', 'of', 'fields', )
```

Posting data to the list URL for this view in the format:

```
[
    {'loads':'foo','of':'bar','fields':'buzz'},
    {'loads':'fizz','of':'bazz','fields':'errrrm'}
]
```

Created two resources with those details. Which was nice.

Comment: Ha, that's a good catch. I've updated my code to actually do something with the now defaulted many value. It was a typing error on my part.

Turns out just sending the data in the format shown does the job via the deprecated method though. Warning, changes are untested.

Comment: What does request.DATA look like in this case?  It can't be a dictionary - or do they stick it in the dict somehow?

Comment: @akaphenom I don't know if you found your answer but it seems that request.DATA can be either a list containing a dict or a dict containing a list containing a dict depending on how you serialize it.  At least that's been my experience.

Comment: its good to know.  I have moved on from django work,so I haven't focused.  But I ma happy to have this answer a little more complete.

Comment: @Yorkot can you help how to do a save and an update for a single post request using modelviewset?

Comment: Updated url mentioned in this response:  http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects

Comment: doesn't work for me
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."
    ]
}

Comment: How about the object include file - and send rquest with fromdata type?

Comment: doesn't solve my problem "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."

my serializer has this field here which won't accept two PKeys whatever i send 
```ingredients = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Ingredient.objects.all())```

Answer (score 77):

I came to a similar conclusion as Daniel Albarral, but here's a more succinct solution:

```
class CreateListModelMixin(object):

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ if an array is passed, set serializer to many """
        if isinstance(kwargs.get('data', {}), list):
            kwargs['many'] = True
        return super(CreateListModelMixin, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This made my day! I confirm this works fine and accepts both lists and dict.

Comment: How is this expected to work given request.data is a QueryDict and not a dict or list? It works in unit tests but not in actual runtime due to that fact (for me, at least).

Comment: kwargs.get('data', {}) will return a QueryDict, and thus fail the ininstance, so many will not be set to True.

Comment: @RogerCollins If one of the list items raises validation error, entire request fails. Is there a way to skip invalid items and create rest of the instances?

Comment: @pnhegde You'd have to include that logic in your serializer.You'd also have a lot of work making sure your front-end updated your model with the results, since the relations would be out of sync.

Answer (score 63):

Here's another solution, you don't need to override your serializers `__init__` method. Just override your view's (ModelViewSet) `'create'` method. Notice `many=isinstance(request.data,list)`. Here `many=True` when you send an array of objects to create, and `False` when you send just the one. This way, you can save both an item and a list!

```
from rest_framework import status, viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response

class ThingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

"""This view snippet provides both list and item create functionality."""

    #I took the liberty to change the model to queryset
    queryset = Thing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ThingSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=isinstance(request.data,list))
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: This answer seems more straight forward and how I would expect this functionality to be implemented.

Comment: This one works and the top voted answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: You can additionally add a `transaction.atomic()` block to make sure all elements are added

Comment: This deserves more vote as this was the only one that worked out for me and it's pretty straightforward too.

Comment: I ran into the: `Expected a dictionary, but got list.` error in the accepted answer and this one fixed it for me. Thanks.

Comment: Whenever I use `many=isinstance(request.data,list)` I get attribute error: `Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 'user' on serializer FileUploadSerializer.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the list instance.
Original exception text was: 'list' object has no attribute 'user'.` Error goes away if I use `many=True` instead.

Comment: Could anyone tell me how to do the same with the update multiple records using:    `def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
             instance = self.get_object()  .......
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data)`

Comment: I was working on similar problem, but in my case, I have to create multiple  objects but some data might throw some error, so for many=true how can we do multiple partial update , i.e let say 6/10 got inserted

Answer (score 17):

I think the best approach to respect the proposed architecture of the framework will be to create a mixin like this:

```
class CreateListModelMixin(object):

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            Create a list of model instances if a list is provided or a
            single model instance otherwise.
        """
        data = request.data
        if isinstance(data, list):
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        else:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                    headers=headers)
```

Then you can override the CreateModelMixin of ModelViewSet like this:

```
class <MyModel>ViewSet(CreateListModelMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    ...
```

Now in the client you can work like this:

```
var things = [    
    {'loads':'foo','of':'bar','fields':'buzz'},
    {'loads':'fizz','of':'bazz','fields':'errrrm'}
]
thingClientResource.post(things)
```

or

```
var thing = {
    'loads':'foo','of':'bar','fields':'buzz'
}
    
thingClientResource.post(thing)
```

EDIT:

As Roger Collins suggests in [his response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40253309/3507146) is more clever to overwrite the get_serializer method than the 'create'.

Comment: Have a feeling Roger is a guy

Answer (score 14):

I couldn't quite figure out getting the request.DATA to convert from a dictionary to an array - which was a limit on my ability to Tom Manterfield's solution to work.   Here is my solution:

```
class ThingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        many = kwargs.pop('many', True)
        super(ThingSerializer, self).__init__(many=many, *args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Thing
        fields = ('loads', 'of', 'fields', )

class ThingViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet ):
    queryset = myModels\
        .Thing\
        .objects\
        .all()
    serializer_class = ThingSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = request.user
        listOfThings = request.DATA['things']

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=listOfThings, files=request.FILES, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                            headers=headers)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And then I run the equivalent of this on the client:

```
var things = {    
    "things":[
        {'loads':'foo','of':'bar','fields':'buzz'},
        {'loads':'fizz','of':'bazz','fields':'errrrm'}]
}
thingClientResource.post(things)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the example. Note, I didn't have to override __init__ in my Serializer, just the create method in my view class

Comment: I didn't think to try it without the init, I was working off of the previous example.  I will definitely try your modification out, and update my answer pending that experiment.  Thanks for the "heads up".

Comment: I think the key is the inclusion of `many=True` in the `get_serializer` call

Comment: It's been over a year since I wrote my answer and I struggle to remember what I had for breakfast, so take this for what it's worth:
I seem to remember the only reason I had to overwrite my init to add the many flag was because I didn't want to directly instantiate the serializer class for some reason (hopefully it was a good one, but right now it escapes me). So yeah, the passing of many=True is the key here. The overridden init can be dropped.

Comment: This example is the only one that works with django 1.9

Comment: I was working on similar problem, but in my case, I have to create multiple objects but some data might throw some error, so for many=true how can we do multiple partial update , i.e let say 6/10 got inserted

Answer (score 10):

You can simply overwrite the `get_serializer` method in your APIView and pass `many=True` into `get_serializer` of the base view like so:

```
class SomeAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer

    def get_serializer(self, instance=None, data=None, many=False, partial=False):
        return super(SomeAPIView, self).get_serializer(instance=instance, data=data, many=True, partial=partial)
```

Comment: When you implement this method you  might get and  "AssertionError" When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the serialized `.data` representation.
You should either call `.is_valid()` first, or access `.initial_data` instead.

Comment: Try the next:
`from rest_framework.fields import empty
def get_serializer(self, instance=None, data=empty, many=False, partial=False):
        return super(SomeAPIView, self).get_serializer(instance=instance, data=data, many=True, partial=partial)`

Comment: Is it possible to override the perform_create or perform_update methods with this and add additional generated values to the individual objects?

Answer (score 7):

I came up with simple example in `post`

Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from movie.models import Movie

class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = [
            'popularity',
            'director',
            'genre',
            'imdb_score',
            'name',
        ]
```

Views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import MovieSerializer
from movie.models import Movie
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class MovieList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:10]
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = MovieSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data
        if isinstance(data, list):  # <- is the main logic
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        else:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

These line are the actual logic of Multiple Instance -

```
data = request.data
if isinstance(data, list):  # <- is the main logic
      serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
else:
      serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
```

[If you are confused with many=True, see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51223456/what-does-many-true-do-in-django-rest-framework)

When we send data it will be inside `list` somewhat like this -

```
[
    {
        "popularity": 84.0,
        "director": "Stanley Kubrick",
        "genre": [
            1,
            6,
            10
        ],
        "imdb_score": 8.4,
        "name": "2001 : A Space Odyssey"
    },
    {
        "popularity": 84.0,
        "director": "Stanley Kubrick",
        "genre": [
            1,
            6,
            10
        ],
        "imdb_score": 8.4,
        "name": "2001 : A Space Odyssey"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Generic Views](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views.html) page in [Django REST Framework's documentation](http://django-rest-framework.org/) states that the [ListCreateAPIView](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views.html#listcreateapiview) generic view is "used for read-write endpoints to represent a collection of model instances".

That's where I would start looking (and I'm going to actually, since we'll need this functionality in our project soon as well).

Note also that the [examples](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views.html#examples) on the Generic Views page happen to use `ListCreateAPIView`.

Comment: I saw that; however, in the tutorial there were no examples that showed how to allow for the creation/update of multiple items. Questions such as do I nest the resources within a json object, should it be flat, what happens if only a subset of items do not validate, etc aren't documented. For now, I did a somewhat inelegant workaround where I loop over a teachers json object and use a teacher serializer to validate and save. Please let me know if you find out a better solution. Thanks

Comment: Yes it looks like to be individual Create and the List functions.  I don't  think the solution of updating / creating multiple records is in there.

Comment: 3 out of 4 links are now broken

Answer (score 4):

Most straightforward method I've come across:

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = ThatSerializer(data=request.data, many=isinstance(request.data, list))
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: You could simply set, `many=True` and it will still work