# Django rest framework: Insert multiple objects in one post request

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF for my API backend. I need to insert multiple objects into one post request. I saw so many tutorials, as well [How do I create multiple model instances with Django Rest Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666199/how-do-i-create-multiple-model-instances-with-django-rest-framework), but not success. I am using ModelSerializer, but when using **many=True** then have problem with ListSerializer.

*views.py*

```
class SaleUserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SaleUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SaleUserSerializer(many=True)
```

*serlializers.py*

```
class SaleUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SaleUser
        fields = ('id', 'comment', 'creation_date', 'modification_date', 'last_user', 'user', 'sale', 'user_sale_type')
```

*error message*

> AttributeError at /api/sale_user/ type object 'Meta' has no attribute 'model'

Please advise.

Comment: Welcome to the stackoverflow.
hi, add your code and error trace, please.

Comment: Thank you Bear, I edited my question with code and error message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

rollback serializer to your default

```
class SaleUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SaleUser
        fields = (
            'id',
            'comment',
            'creation_date',
            'modification_date',
            'last_user',
            'user',
            'sale',
            'user_sale_type'
        )
```

and override view to it:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response    

class SaleUserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SaleUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SaleUserSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data.get('items', request.data)
        many = isinstance(data, list)
        print (data, many)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data, many=many)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(
                serializer.data,
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                headers=headers
        )
```

Comment: I rewrite `data = request.data.get("items") if 'items' in request.data else data = request.data` to `        if 'items' in request.data:
            data = request.data.get("items")
        else:
            data = request.data` because I get this error `SyntaxError: can't assign to conditional expression` With rewrited code still get error `AssertionError at /api/sale_user/
Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.`

Comment: i'm sorry, i fixed both troubles you may try again

Comment: Ok, I tried again, now I have new error `NameError at /api/sale_user/
name 'status' is not defined` :(

Comment: it is good :)
just add `from rest_framework import status` to your imports

Comment: glad to help you)

Comment: getting error - name 'Response' is not defined. Although data is stored. Any advice on that?

Comment: Got rid of it using 'from rest_framework.response import Response'.

Comment: @yaksh added the import to the answer, for other who will search the same

Comment: Hi @BearBrown, I would really appreciate if you can suggest any good place where I can learn Django Rest Framework in-depth. I have tried DRF documentation but it is a little tough for me.

Comment: Hi, for me the good books is:[Two-Scoops-Django](https://www.amazon.com/Two-Scoops-Django-1-11-Practices/dp/0692915729/ref=pd_sbs_14_1/137-3095740-2195057?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=0692915729&pd_rd_r=bafad847-9834-45b0-bf8f-f93ac9031871&pd_rd_w=IZFXK&pd_rd_wg=SXsLn&pf_rd_p=12b8d3e2-e203-4b23-a8bc-68a7d2806477&pf_rd_r=9KQPWWMQM7P45Z7FWC58&psc=1&refRID=9KQPWWMQM7P45Z7FWC58)