# ListSerializer in Django Restful - When is it called?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following code for my `serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from django.db import transaction
from secdata_finder.models import File

class FileListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    @transaction.atomic
    def batch_save_files(file_data):
        files = [File(**data) for data in file_data]
        return File.objects.bulk_create(files)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("I am creating multiple rows!")
        return self.batch_save_files(validated_data)

class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = FileListSerializer
        model = File
        fields = (...) # omitted
```

I'm experimenting with it on my Django test suite:

```
def test_file_post(self):
    request = self.factory.post('/path/file_query', {"many":False})
    request.data = {
        ... # omitted fields here
    }
    response = FileQuery.as_view()(request)
```

It prints `I am creating multiple rows!`, which is **not what should happen**.

Per the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer):

> ... customize the create or update behavior of multiple objects.
>   For these cases you can modify the class that is used when many=True is passed, by using the list_serializer_class option on the serializer Meta class.

So what am I not understanding? I passed in `many:False` in my post request, and yet it still delegates the `create` function to the `FileListSerializer`!

Comment: `{"many": False}` in the POST request doesn't mean anything to the serializer. Are you passing in the keyword arg `many=False` when instantiating the serializer in your API View? You should add code for your view here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create multiple model instances with Django Rest Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666199/how-do-i-create-multiple-model-instances-with-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the docs:

> The ListSerializer class provides the behavior for serializing and
>   validating multiple objects at once. You won't typically need to use
>   ListSerializer directly, but should instead simply pass many=True when
>   instantiating a serializer

You can add `many=True` to your serializer

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['many'] = kwargs.get('many', True)
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Potential dupe of [How do I create multiple model instances with Django Rest Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666199/how-do-i-create-multiple-model-instances-with-django-rest-framework)