# How to create multiple model instances without duplicated writable nested serializer in Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two related models: `Product` and `ProductDescription`. In 1 submit action user able to insert a new `Product` with multiple descriptions depend on the available languages. I use writable nested serializer to insert into `Product` and `ProductDescription` simultaneously. I do it by overriding `create` function in `ProductDescriptionSerializer` class, it works. However, I can only insert 1 `ProductDescription` at a time.

Then I tried to use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40253309/5752558) to create multiple model instances at once. The problem is it also creates the same `Product` twice instead of using the newly created `Product` Id to insert the next `ProductDescription`.

My `models.py`:

```
class Product(models.Model, ProductStatus):
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    color = models.ForeignKey(ColorParent, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(ProductCollection, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    video = models.URLField(verbose_name='Video URL', max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ProductStatus.status, default=ProductStatus.active)


class ProductDescription(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.product, self.language)
```

My `serializers.py`:

```
class CustomRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def display_value(self, instance):
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return str(value)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        model = self.queryset.model
        return model.objects.get(id=data)


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    collection = CustomRelatedField(queryset=ProductCollection.objects.all(), many=False)
    color = CustomRelatedField(queryset=ColorParent.objects.all(), many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'product_code', 'collection', 'color', 'video', 'status']


class ProductDescriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer()
    language = CustomRelatedField(many=False, queryset=Language.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = ProductDescription
        fields = ['id', 'product', 'language', 'description']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        if self.context['request'].method == 'GET':
            data['product'] = instance.product.product_code
            return data
        return Serializer.to_representation(self, instance)

    # The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # create product data for Product model.
        product_data = validated_data.pop('product')
        product = Product.objects.create(**product_data)

        # create ProductDescription and set product FK.
        product_description = ProductDescription.objects.create(product=product, **validated_data)

        # return ProductDescription instance.
        return product_description
```

My `views.py`:

```
class CreateListModelMixin(object):
    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(kwargs.get('data', {}), list):
            kwargs['many'] = True
        return super(CreateListModelMixin, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)


class ProductDescriptionView(CreateListModelMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.DjangoModelPermissions]
    queryset = ProductDescription.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductDescriptionSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'head', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete']
```

The JSON format I use to POST data:

```
[
  {
    "product": {
        "product_code": "BQ1080",
        "collection": 5,
        "color": 7,
        "video": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=",
        "status": "Continue"
    },
    "language": 1,
    "description": "English description."
  },
  {
    "product": {
        "product_code": "BQ1080",
        "collection": 5,
        "color": 7,
        "video": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=",
        "status": "Continue"
    },
    "language": 2,
    "description": "Vietnamese description."
  }
]
```

It creates a duplicate `Product` in Product List:

```
[
    {
        "id": 26,
        "product_code": "BQ1080",
        "collection": 5,
        "color": 7,
        "video": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=",
        "status": "Continue"
    },
    {
        "id": 27,
        "product_code": "BQ1080",
        "collection": 5,
        "color": 7,
        "video": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=",
        "status": "Continue"
    }
]
```

The `ProductDescription` datas are correct though:

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "product": "BQ1080",
        "language": "English",
        "description": "English description."
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "product": "BQ1080",
        "language": "Vietnam",
        "description": "Vietnamese description."
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid duplicate product you can use [`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create) method:

```
class ProductDescriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # create product data for Product model.
        product_data = validated_data.pop('product')
        product_code = product_data.pop("product_code") 
        product, _ = Product.objects.get_or_create(product_code=product_code, defaults=product_data)

        # create ProductDescription and set product FK.
        product_description = ProductDescription.objects.create(product=product, **validated_data)

        # return ProductDescription instance.
        return product_description
```

Note that `get_or_create` is prone to race condition. So if two same requests came to you service at the same time you may still have duplicate products.

Comment: I got  `"non_field_errors": ["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."]` when I used the same JSON format as in my post. How do I post the new data format?

Comment: @Nathan it strange,  did you changed something else? You should still use solution with many=True. Do not remove it.

Comment: Sorry. I did mistakenly change something. It works now. Thank you neverwalkaloner!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to override your `ProductSerializer`'s create method. Maybe you can try like this:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    collection = CustomRelatedField(queryset=ProductCollection.objects.all(), many=False)
    color = CustomRelatedField(queryset=ColorParent.objects.all(), many=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance, _ = Product.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data)
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'product_code', 'collection', 'color', 'video', 'status']
```

So that, first it will try to get if the Product exists, else create the instance(hence reducing duplicate entry).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, ruddra. The `Product` instance still inserted twice. Should I add/change another part of my code as well?

Answer (score 0):

`ForeignKey` not for this job you should use `ManyToManyField`