# Updating multiple objects with one request in Django and Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, view, django-rest-framework

I need to update multiple Education objects at a time from one request.
My Views is:

```
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial, many=True) # many = True for multiple update
        if serializer.is_valid():
            self.perform_update(serializer)            
            response = create_response(True,data = serializer.data)        
            return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            response =  create_response(False, err_name = serializer._errors)
            return Response(response, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and  my serializer is :

```
    class Meta:
        model = Education
        fields = ['user','level', 'institute', 'start_date', 'complete_date']
```

'many=True' is only work for multiple objects create. 
How to update multiple objects at a time?

Education Model:

```
class Education(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeInfo, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=QUALIFICATION)
    institute = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    complete_date = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
```

Comment: Your question is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666199/how-do-i-create-multiple-model-instances-with-django-rest-framework

Comment: Could you post your model too

Comment: @BakhtiyarBekbergen yes.  i post my model with question

Comment: serializer automatically will get queryset of objects list by one request, and then you can use setattr to change fields value without save, and outside of loop you will do bulk create which will create/update you Education objects by one request to your database

Comment: @BakhtiyarBekbergen can you give any example for this?

Comment: you can find usefull information here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once