# upload multiple images without forms in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-file-upload

This is my models.py

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/')
```

serializers.py

```
class UploadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Upload
    fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class UploadViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Upload.objects.all()
permission_classes = [
    permissions.AllowAny
]
serializer_class = UploadSerializer
```

I can successfully upload single image, however django model is not recieving multiple images at once. How to upload multiple images? what should i change in serializers.py or models.py or views.py? any related response is appreciable. Thank you.

Comment: What would you do if you receive multiple images? Would you save those **N** files as ***separate `Upload` instances***?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Yes already i can save images in images folder with the help of upload_to in models.py but only works with single image :(  i will then process that images with machine learning, say like image processing. uploading images from react to django is working fine but only single image can be uploaded because i have to change something in Django, but i dont know what to change since i'm not expert in Django.