# Django rest framework API with filter

Tags: django, filter, django-rest-framework

**Models.py**

Categories:

```
class Category_product(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
```

Products:

```
class Warehouse(models.Model):
    category_product = models.ForeignKey(
    Category_product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    condition = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    barcode = models.BigIntegerField()
    f_price = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

**urls.py**

```
   path('products-list/', views.WarehouseList.as_view()),
```

**Views.py**

```
class WarehouseList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Warehouse.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WarehouseSerializer
```

**Serializers.py**

```
# SERIALIZER OF CATEGORY PRODUCTS
class Category_productSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category_product
        fields = ['id', 'category_name']


# SERIALIZER OF WAREHOUSE
class WarehouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
category_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
    source='category_product.category_name')

def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(kwargs.get('data', {}), list):
        kwargs['many'] = True
    return super(Category_productSerializer, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    model = Warehouse
    fields = ['id', 'category_product', 'category_name', 'condition',
              'product_name', 'amount', 'barcode', 'f_price', 'created_at', 'updated_at']
```

I want to get products by exact category

For example:
I have product category

```
{
"id": 1 
"category_name": "Electronics"
}
```

If I send **GET** request to `api/products-list/?cat=1`
I want to get products which have this category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `get_queryset` method as follow.

```py
class WarehouseList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = WareHouse.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WarehouseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
       cat = self.request.query_params.get('cat', None)       
       if cat is not None:
            self.queryset = self.queryset.filter(category_product__id=cat)
       return self.queryset
```

Comment: Now it returns _'WarehouseList' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method. _

Comment: Posted, after  views.py

Comment: Thank's, now it works! I'll remember you when i became great developer:)

Comment: My suggestion for you is to learn python well, so that you will be able to read code of django rest framework. Then you can solve all drf related problems on your own. Granted, It will be difficult and take time. But there is no other way. Best of luck!

Comment: Where should I use many="True" if I want to POST multiple objects at once?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666199/how-do-i-create-multiple-model-instances-with-django-rest-framework. I'd  go with the second answer (sorted by votes).

Comment: I changed serializers.py above.

Comment: And I'm getting error    "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."

Comment: You should override CreateModelMixin. Forget it. Go with 3rd answer. Just a  copy paste. It will be easy, though it does not seem  very elegant.